# How to execute SWI-prolog command from shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, prolog, swi-prolog

As a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467090/how-to-run-swi-prolog-from-the-command-line), now I am wondering if there is a way to execute/evaluate a prolog predicate/expression straight from the shell, something like this:

```
$ swipl --eval "-:pack_install(something)"
```

Is something like that possible? Like in node.js, you can do:

```
$ node -e "console.log('hello world');"
```

And it will load up node, evaluate the expression, and close.

How do you do the equivalent in prolog?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the particular Prolog implementation. E.g. in SWI-Prolog, your can type:

```
$ swipl -g "write(hello), nl, halt"
hello
```

For more details, consult the man page:

```
$ man swipl
```