# running prolog as a script

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

So, I have some Prolog code that models variable assignments, such as in a programming language, and tries to see if they are compatible with one another. So,

```
assigned(X, X).
and(P, Q) :- P, Q.
or(P, Q) :- P.
or(P, Q) :- Q.

% and then we should test an expression like this:
and(assigned(X, 5), assigned(X, 6)).
```

So that last expression fails, since `X` can't be assigned to both 5 and 6.

Now, what I want to do is have this test a single expression (which can and should be hardcoded into the file), and then simply print out whether or not it's able to be satisfied. But it seems that SWIPL *really* wants me to run interactively. Ideally, something like this:

```
> ./test-assignments
false.
```

Surely this is possible? I'm at my wit's end on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to get an SWI-Prolog program to run directly from the shell. You can look at this question and the answers:

[How to run SWI-Prolog from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467090/how-to-run-swi-prolog-from-the-command-line)

My personal preference now is to have a file `example.pl` like this:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(verbose, silent).
:- initialization(main).

main :-
    format('Example script~n'),
    current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
    format('Called with ~q~n', [Argv]),
    halt.
main :-
    halt(1).
```

which I then run from the command line with:

```
$ swipl example.pl and a few arguments
Example script
Called with [and,a,few,arguments]
```

The initialization directive tells the interpreter which goal to evaluate after it loads the program: here it is `main/0`. The name `main` is a convention, it could have been called anything else.

See the linked question and answers for other options.

Comment: `initialization/1` is an ISO-directive.

Comment: @false Yes, do you mean that it should rather be `:- initialization(main).`?

Comment: Yes! That is one obstacle less.