# How to run a PROLOG script file in BATCH mode? (in Linux Terminal)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, prolog, batch-processing, swi-prolog

I'm trying to use a PROLOG script file with Rules
in Batch mode, (not interactive mode).

Using **swi-prolog** in **Ubuntu Linux**,
it works well in Prolog's interactive mode.

But how to run prolog in Batch mode? (not interactive mode).

So, the objective is to call **swipl** with a query argument
and see the results
as output in Terminal.

Ideally,
to also see in the Terminal output,
which Rule(s) are "true" for each input query.

My prolog **db.pl** file:

```
likes(john,jane).    
likes(jane,john).    
likes(jack,jane).    

% and a single Rule below:    
friends(X,Y) :- likes(X,Y) , likes(Y, X).
```

I tried to run in Terminal:

```
swipl -s db.pl -t friends(X,Y)
```

where:

```
friends(X,Y)
```

is the goal/query I want to evaluate
via the Rule in db.pl.

Expected result:

```
john,jane
```

Ideal output with "true" Rule numbers:

```
john,jane,Rule01
```

Actual result:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can not find a simple code example
on how to accomplish this objective in prolog...

Comment: That's because bash processes parentheses on the command line. You'll probably need to put the query in quotes: `... -t "friends(X,Y)"`.

Comment: You might also want to look at this: [How to run SWI Prolog from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467090/how-to-run-swi-prolog-from-the-command-line)

Comment: thank you, Lurker but:
  swipl  db.pl -t "friends(X,Y)"
single or double-quotes, 
just opens the interactive version of swipl...no luck with that solution...

Comment: Right. You still need to tell it to execute your goal. Check the other link I provided. Also you can Google "swipl command line execution" or something similar. There are several useful posts on this topic.

Comment: Hi Lurker. Yes, checked it
and it works with their "Hello World" string example.

I'm sweating trying to make it work
using and evaluating the query arg: 
   'friends(X,Y)'
and then outputing  the result of the call:
swipl  db.pl 'friends(X,Y)'

Comment: do you want to put a 'halt' goal in after your query? Then prolog will exit so your back on the normal terminal?

Comment: @user27815: Yep!  That halt to exit swipl makes sense!. We need to avoid swipl opening in Terminal and "prompting" the user for input. The idea is that the query arg, - ie:  'friends(X,Y)'  is passed to swipl as an argument. Then swipl outputs the result to Terminal and exits...