# Prolog: Print to swi prolog console immediately I consult a file

Tags: prolog

I have a simple prolog program:

```
write_manual:-
   write('------------------------------'),
   write('USAGE MANUAL'),
   write('find_course. - List all the available courses'),
   write('------------------------------').
   % execute this and output this right away when I open the program in the console
```

Does anyone know to achieve this? I'd like to print a simple help manual before the program starts. Currently, the **swi prolog console** (on windows 10) shows the ?- prompt and requires me to 
manually call the predicate. I'm using  SWI-Prolog  `(threaded, 64 bits, version 8.0.0)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run SWI-Prolog from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467090/how-to-run-swi-prolog-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @GuyCoder havent been able to get `initialization main.` to work (nothing is output to the swi console). I'm running the program using the `file > consult` option of the swi prolog console (not shell).

Comment: @GuyCoder see the edits. Yes, I'm running on windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is a comment* posted in a question because it doesn't format correctly in a comment.

Running on Windows 10 with `SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.21)`

```
:- initialization main.

main :-
    write_manual.

write_manual :-
    format('------------------------------~n',[]),
    format('USAGE MANUAL~n',[]),
    format('find_course. - List all the available courses~n',[]),
    format('------------------------------~n',[]).
```

Start SWI-Prolog

```
?- consult("C:/Prolog/SO_question_160.pl").
------------------------------
USAGE MANUAL
find_course. - List all the available courses
------------------------------
true.

?-
```

Note: This was not setup to start from a Windows command line script because the title of the question reads `I consult a file`.

Comment: That is what I don't get about SO, I get more points from comments like this where I don't want the points, than I do from great answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53412988/1243762) where it would nice to get more up-votes.

Comment: @false 12 = 4 hours, 1 = 30 seconds. Units of measure.

Comment: @GuyCoder the swi prolog console on windows 10 has an option to consult/run program from file `menu > file > consult`. (I edited the title). Also, I'm relatively new to ai and prolog so I'm still getting acquainted to the usage and paradigms as well