# Finding Paths in Prolog

Tags: path, prolog, nodes, path-finding, transitive-closure

I'm relatively new to Prolog and my aim from this code is to try and find all routes between all defined edges. Prolog should output me the full route from the inputted start to destination. However I keep getting an error `bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ('`

I was wondering if im going about this in the right way? or maybe I'm being blind to silly mistakes..

Here is my code.

```
edge(o,p1).
edge(p1,k).
edge(k,l).
edge(l,c).
edge(c,b).
edge(c,w).
edge(c,m).
edge(l,p2).


path(X,Y,Path) :- path(X,Y,[X],Q), reverse(Q,Path).


path(X,Y,Visited,[Y|Visited]) :- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y,Visited,Path) :-
    edge(X,Z),
    Z \== Y,
    \+ member(Z,Visited),
    path(Z,Y,[Z|Visited],Path).
```

The TEST CASE I was trying to run was

```
path(o, m, Path).
```

edit: i ran it with swipl and these errors were returned
[image here, it didnt let me upload an image sorry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnWq4.png)

Comment: What command are you using to try and execute this?  What queries do you plan on using to test your code?

Comment: @ScottHunter Edited & added test case in post

Comment: What command are you using to try and execute this?

Comment: I copied this verbatim, used your query and got `Path = [o, p1, k, l, c, m] ; false.`

Comment: Say `?- path(edge, Path, o, m).` with [this definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868).

Comment: Your error suggests you are trying to run it as a Linux shell script like `./paths.pl` and Bash is trying to interpret it. You need to run it through `swipl` somehow or other - see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=plscript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467090/how-to-run-swi-prolog-from-the-command-line for some options